# What's the difference between two ways of using new operator?

Tags: c++, new-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)

Suppose we have a class named `SomeClass`. What's the difference of the following two ways using `new`?

```
SomeClass *p1 = new SomeClass;
SomeClass *p2 = new SomeClass();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new.